# How communicate between multiple raspberry pis over the internet?

Tags: camera, internet, communication

0

I am working on a project with raspberry pi. I have a little experience with raspberry pi, but not so much.

The project is as folows: There are 3 raspberry pi's with each a camera. One raspberry pi is the master, and the other two are the slaves. Each raspberry takes a photo and send it to the master. So that the master can put the photos in an document. I was thinking of creating a python script. The pi's communicate with each other over the internet. (IP addresses are fixed)

I'm not sure what to use for this. What's the best way I can do this?

Comment: this is not a Raspberry Pi specific question ... please research in the Linux realm

Comment: You can send pictures as a MQTT payload. Search for how to use MQTT to publish a message (from a subordinate machine) to broker so that it is delivered to a subscriber (main machine).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to know how to help you without more information. You could use BASH and SSH to automate secure connections + file transfers.